# Canon R6 makes cleaning noises when is turned off and the Lens is unmounted

Tags: canon

I have a R6 since about a half year. Not sure if I never noticed it or if this just started to happen.

When the Cam is turned off, and I un/mount a lens it seems that the cam is doing the sensor cleaning procedure.

Is that normal or should I have it checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does that. I have R6. I also have RP and if I recall correctly, RP does that too.

This behaviour of these mirrorless cameras (R6, RP) differs entirely from every Canon DSLR with cleaning cycle that I have used. 70D and 90D run cleaning cycle on power-on/off events. R6 and RP also run the cleaning cycle when changing the lens, despite the fact that the camera may have been powered off for hours, days or even weeks without being turned on. I suspect the theory is that on DLSRs, there are two layers of protection against sensor dust: (1) shutter, (2) mirror. Mirrorless cameras lack the mirror, and some cheap mirrorless cameras such as RP have electronic first-curtain shutter so the shutter is open when power is off. So on RP there is absolutely no protection on the sensor when changing the lens.

So on DSLRs, the triggers for cleaning are power-on and power-off events. On mirrorless cameras (at least Canon), there is an additional trigger: lens change, even though the lens change may be performed at a time the camera is powered off and has been powered off for ages.

The theory probably is that lens changes can introduce dirt inside the camera, so that's the best possible moment for doing sensor self-cleaning cycle.

If you think about it, if you never change a lens it's unlikely to end up with sensor dirt. Well maybe if the lens is a zoom lens, it could act as an air pump introducing dirt to the sensor. But a prime, probably not.

If you hate that, you can of course remove the battery, replace the lens, and only then reinsert the battery. But the lens self-cleaning cycle is beneficial so why would you avoid it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not have a problem with it. I just had the camera quiet a while and never noticed it before, so I thought this might be something that has started to happen newly and got worried a bit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Every Canon EOS camera body I've ever owned runs the self cleaning cycle by default each time the camera is powered up and each time it is powered down unless either of the two events occur within a specific time interval from the last time the automatic cleaning routine was ran. So if you turn the camera on and off in rapid succession within a few seconds, it will only run the self cleaning routine when  you first turn it on. If you leave the camera on for several minutes, it will run it again when you turn it off. Ditto for turning the camera off after it's been on for a while, then turning it right back on. It will run the routine when you turn it off, but won't run it again when you turn it right back on a few seconds later.

I do not have any experience with the R6 model, but I'd be very surprised if it doesn't follow the same behavior by default.

This can be modified in the menu for at least most, if not all, models. But I've never heard of a camera wearing out prematurely due to excessive use of the self cleaning function, so it makes sense to me to let the camera do it.

Comment: This is not the reason. The reason is that on these mirrorless cameras, lens cleaning cycle is done after lens changes with camera powered off. It's not due to the turn-on or turn-off cleaning cycle. It's an entirely different trigger for the cleaning cycle.

Comment: Please re-read the above answer more carefully. The answer says the camera runs the cleaning cycle each time it is turned off *unless* the cleaning cycle has already been run in the last few seconds. You're saying the cleaning cycle being run when the camera is turned off is not due to the fact the camera runs the cleaning cycle when it is turned off?

Comment: I still disagree with this being the reason. I updated my answer to be more clear. I think when the OP mentions "turned off", it means "has been turned off for ages" and does not mean "has been recently turned off".